# How pre-filter messages in a windows service project

Tags: c#, filter, windows-services, message

my windows service codes looks like this :

```
namespace Windows_Service
{
    static class Program
    {
            static void Main()
            {
                try
                {
                    if (IsInstalled())
                    {
                        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                            { 
                                new My_Service() 
                            };
                        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        InstallService();
                        StartService();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
    ...
```

for the first time when i run the exe file my goal service is installed and runned.
for the second time and abow when i click on exe file i got this message :

[image: Windows Service Start Failure]

> Cannot start service from the command line or debugger. A windows
>   Service must first be installed(using installutil.exe) and then
>   started with the ServerExplorer, Windows Services Afministrative tool
>   or the NET START command.

i want to filer this message and prevent this message to comes up.
as you know my project type in windows service and i could n't use the below way :
[How To Pre-Filter Windows Messages](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/chrisblake/howtopre-filterwindowsmessgaes11232005225819pm/howtopre-filterwindowsmessgaes.aspx)

what is the solution and how can i remove that message?

thanks in advance

Comment: no even a comment, :( did i do something wrong?

Comment: Just insert System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); to the OnStart method of your Service and then start it as usual by using net start or from corresponding Windows control Panel.... then you will be able to debug it...

Comment: @Vladimir Gondarev thanks for the comment, would you please show us codes...

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in avoiding telling the user (well, you) that he can't start a service from the command line.  The hint that NET START is required is of course a very useful one.  Suppressing it would make the user think the service got started.  It didn't.